# How do I create a new array with a javascript for loop. I got the error "circular object Object"

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create a new array by dividing the returned array with ajax.
I will copy the objects with offerCurrencyTypeExchanges value as much as the number of this array and write the code and rate value to the "label" value.
But I think I created an error in the loop. copying the last value to all.

Result looks better in jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/xd68no54/

```
var res = [{
    id: 3,
    name: "Türk Lirası",
    code: "TRY",
    offerCurrencyTypeExchanges: [],
    label: "Türk Lirası (TRY)"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "USD",
    code: "USD",
    offerCurrencyTypeExchanges: [{
        exchangeRateId: 33642,
        localize: "Alış",
        value: 9.2857,
        valueSection: 1
      },
      {
        exchangeRateId: 33642,
        localize: "Satış",
        value: 9.3024,
        valueSection: 2
      },
      {
        exchangeRateId: 33642,
        localize: "Efektif alış",
        value: 9.2792,
        valueSection: 3
      },
      {
        exchangeRateId: 33642,
        localize: "Efektif satış",
        value: 9.3164,
        valueSection: 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "EUR",
    code: "EUR",
    offerCurrencyTypeExchanges: [{
        exchangeRateId: 33643,
        localize: "Alış",
        value: 10.8108,
        valueSection: 1
      },
      {
        exchangeRateId: 33643,
        localize: "Satış",
        value: 10.8303,
        valueSection: 2
      },
      {
        exchangeRateId: 33643,
        localize: "Efektif alış",
        value: 10.8033,
        valueSection: 3
      },
      {
        exchangeRateId: 33643,
        localize: "Efektif satış",
        value: 10.8465,
        valueSection: 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "TRY",
    code: "TRY",
    offerCurrencyTypeExchanges: [],
    label: "TRY (TRY)"
  }
]


var resultAutoComplete = [];
var arrInObj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
  if (res[i].offerCurrencyTypeExchanges.length == 0) {
    arrInObj = {
      code: res[i].code,
      id: res[i].id,
      name: res[i].name,
      label: res[i].label = res[i].name + " " + "(" + res[i].code + ")"
    }
    resultAutoComplete.push(arrInObj)

  } else {
    arrInObj = {
      code: res[i].code,
      id: res[i].id,
      name: res[i].name,
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < res[i].offerCurrencyTypeExchanges.length; j++) {
      arrInObj.label = res[i].code + " - " + res[i].offerCurrencyTypeExchanges[j].localize + "(" + res[i].offerCurrencyTypeExchanges[j].value + ")";
      arrInObj.exchangeRateId = res[i].offerCurrencyTypeExchanges[j].exchangeRateId
      arrInObj.localize = res[i].offerCurrencyTypeExchanges[j].localize
      arrInObj.value = res[i].offerCurrencyTypeExchanges[j].value
      arrInObj.valueSection = res[i].offerCurrencyTypeExchanges[j].valueSection
      resultAutoComplete.push(arrInObj)
    }
  }
  console.log(resultAutoComplete)
}
```

Comment: Tip: you should strip non-relevant code if you want more or higher quality answers

Comment: Assign `arrInObj` each time through the loop, not before the loop.

Comment: You're pushing the same object each time.

Comment: Yes all I have to do is define the arrInObj object inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not really I understand what you want to do, but you can extract your objects and do what you want with all of them.

```js
const currencyExchangeTypes = res.map((c) => c.offerCurrencyTypeExchanges).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
```